# Two Java versions might be conflicted in team collaboration?

Tags: java

Here's the thing:

Me and my teammates are now working on a Java project, but I'm almost new to Java development. The thing is that I recently updated my local Java version to 15.0.2, however, they created the project with JDK 1.8 (Java 8 perhaps?).

We are worried that this might cause some conflicts since our Java versions are not corresponding, and I'm also not familiar with the relationship between Java version and JDK version (Just like Java 8 and JDK 1.8).

Could somebody give me some explanations of this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, you probably want the same version. And Java 1.8 is 8, due to some naming shenanigans. You want the latest version that works with your system if you can. Does that answer your question?

Comment: As a Java developer, you usually have several JDKs in your system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> We are worried that this might cause some conflicts since our Java versions are not corresponding ...

Yes, you could run into problems:

- There are significant differences in the Java language and Java standard class libraries between Java 8 and Java 15.  Code written for Java 15 using Java 15 may not compile on Java 8.
- Java 8 and Java 15 tool chains produce compiled code with different classfile version numbers.  Code compiled for Java 15 will not run on a Java 8 platform.

It is possible to work around these problems, but it is much simpler if all project members use the same Java version.

If you are new to Java, my recommendation is to install and use Java 8.  Note that it is possible to have different versions of Java installed simultaneously, and use different versions for different projects.

---

> ... and I'm also not familiar with the relationship between Java version and JDK version (Just like Java 8 and JDK 1.8).

It is pretty straightforward.  Java 8 is JDK 1.8, Java 9 is JDK 1.9, and so on.  This started with Java 5 / JDK 1.5

The weird numbering is a result of a Sun Management / Marketing decision when naming Java 5:

> *"The number "5.0" is used to better reflect the level of maturity, stability, scalability and security of the J2SE."*

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/relnotes/version-5.0.html

(You could also say that the people who made this decision didn't understand the principles of semantic version numbering.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! BTW, I'm using Intellij Idea and I can set language level to 8 while using JDK15 to build in project settings. Will this be helpful to avoid the problem of inconsistency of Java versions?

Comment: Not sure.  That is probably sufficient.